# Verify authenticity of the downloaded file

Tags: security, hash, server, cryptography, verification

What is the best way to verify the authenticity of the downloaded file in server-to-server scenario?

Possible option: Generate checksum and then compare it. But how can servers then securely exchange the hashes for matching, if the network is assumed to be compromised?

Are there any other ways to verify authenticity? I’ve read about signatures, but don’t really undestand how they work. Is it something to consider?

I am trying to make sure that no one has tampered with files. Any advise or tips greatly appreciated!

Edit: I do use HTTPS for the traffic between servers, but would like to rely on alternative methods too.

Comment: *"I do use HTTPS for the traffic between servers, but would like to rely on alternative methods too."* - Why? Cryptography for the sake of cryptography is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do use HTTPS for the traffic between servers, but would like to rely on alternative methods too.

HTTPS does protect the communication but not the authenticity of the message. So you are doing the right thing looking ways to authenticate the message.

I suggest you sign the file with the sender's private key and validate the signature at the destination with the public key. Deploy the public key on the server manually before going live so that it cannot be spoofed in transfer.

So in practice one simple working solution would be to use ECDSA or RSA (PSS) signing algorithm to sign a secure hash of the file (e.g. SHA-256).

Another approach could be to use HMAC if you can protect the key on both ends.

Comment: HTTPS needs some kind of trust root to work. If there is one, then an HTTPS connection has the consequence that the client is sure that anything that the server sends is authentic. HMAC provides integrity and not authentication is in the strong sense, because both parties have the symmetric HMAC-key and can "sign" any data.

Comment: @Artjom B. I must disagree with you. HTTPS will not guarantee the authenticity of the message. The receiver cannot know if the data has been manipulated at rest before the transfer. Also if your communication path has multiple hops, you need to go extra mile to ensure authentication of every hop if you don't sign your data at the source.

Comment: Hey @quinz, thanks for your reply! I'll look further into signing of the message.

Comment: *"The receiver cannot know if the data has been manipulated at rest before the transfer."* - That's right. HTTPS is for data in flight, but without a proper description of a use case of your signing solution, it doesn't provide better authenticity than HTTPS. Have you thought about how the public key (verifying key) is kept at the receiving end? If an attacker is able to breach the receiver and manipulate the files, what makes you thing that the attacker can't also manipulate the public key that is also kept at the receiver?

Comment: I provided a high level idea for a high level question. Cannot provide more detailed solution without knowing more details of the problem. There are multiple possibilities to validate the public key that I can think of. Feel free to open a question in security.stackexchange.com and I'll give you some ideas. For this question I think they are out of scope since it would get way too broad to handle without the details.

Comment: Nice touch with the down vote though. Cannot please everybody :)